# Como definir uma propriedade privada no Python? E existe propriedade protegida?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método, getters-setters

Eu venho do PHP. Nele, quando queremos definir uma propriedade de uma classe como privada adicionarmos a palavra chave `private` na sua declaração.

Exemplo:

```php
class StackOverflow extends StackExchange
{
    private $language = 'en'; // privado, só pode ser acessado via Accessor!

    public function __construct($language === null){
            
            if ($language !== null) {
                $this->language = $language;
            }

    }

    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }
}
```

Agora gostaria de saber como fazer isso no `Python`. Como definir a propriedade privada nesse exemplo abaixo.

```
class StackExchange(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class StackOverflow(StackExchange):

    language = 'en' // quero que seja privado ou protegido!
    
    def __init__(self, language = None):
        if language is not None:
            self.language = language


sopt = StackOverflow('pt')
sopt.language // retorna o valor, mas quero utilizar um Accessor ao invés disso
```

Outra coisa: No PHP, utilizamos `protected` para definir que a propriedade não pode ser acessada na instanciação da classe, porém pode ser acessada por ela mesma e por quem a herda.

Tem como fazer isso no Python também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Conforme a resposta do @JoãoPedroAlves, não existe propriedade privada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53030/2999).

Para propriedades protegidas, seria um esquema usando os modificadores [`@property` e `@nomedaproperty.setter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class StackExchange(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class StackOverflow(StackExchange):
    # Coloque sua variável dentro de __init__, o que "evita" que ela vire pública.
    # Ela ainda é acessível através de _StackOverflow__language.
    def __init__(self, language = None):
        self.__language = 'en'
        if language is not None:
            self.__language = language

    @property # Objeto.language cai aqui
    def language(self):
        return self.__language

    @language.setter # Objeto.language = 'pt' cai aqui
    def name(self, language):
        self.__language = language
```

[Aqui você pode testar](http://pythonfiddle.com/prova-de-conceito-53028).

Comment: Só para refrescar meu cérebro? São dois underlines? tipo len('__') `2`?

Comment: Sim. Exatamente.

Answer (score 5):

Em Python **não existe** esse conceito de propriedade privada.

Seguindo o [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), você pode utilizar o `__` na frente de um método como uma convenção. Lembrando que seu método não será "privado", mas seria uma espécie de convenção para quem vê seu código saber que esse método (ou variável) só deve ser utilizado na classe pai.

Segue um trecho do PEP 0008:

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes
>   that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with
>   double leading underscores and no trailing underscores. This invokes
>   Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is
>   mangled into the attribute name. This helps avoid attribute name
>   collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the
>   same name.

Comment: Ainda assim, dá pra acessar a variável através de `_StackOverflow__language`, como no exemplo que ele pediu.

Comment: E sempre dará. Como dito acima, não existe o conceito de variável privada.

Comment: Nem um enclausuramentozinho básico?

Comment: O mais perto que chega disso é utilizando __ em métodos ou variáveis. Nesse caso eles não poderão ser chamados publicamente...