# É possível criar métodos privados para classes em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem

Em Rust, é possível criar um módulo onde alguns métodos associados a um `struct` são privados. Entendo que a utilidade disso é deixar disponível para o usuário final do módulo apenas os métodos importantes para o uso, enquanto os métodos privados são usados para tarefas internas de quem criou e/ou mantém o módulo.

Exemplo:

```rust
pub struct Player {
    pub username: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub age: u32,
    pub rating: f64,
    pub active: bool,
}

impl Player {
    pub fn double_age(&self) -> u32 {
        return 2*self.age
    }
}

impl Player {
    fn half_rating(&self) -> f64 {
        return 0.5*self.rating
    }
}
```

Se esse módulo for importado por outro arquivo, então o usuário final terá acesso apenas ao método `double_age`, marcado como público (`pub`), mas não terá acesso a `half_rating` (privado por default).

Existe um equivalente dessa característica em Python? Muitas vezes crio métodos para classes em determinados pacotes que gostaria de usar apenas internamente, sem deixar disponível para o usuário final.

Comment: Python não tem métodos privados. Pode haver nomes iniciados com `__` para evitar conflito de qualificação. Muitas pessoas acham que isso é um tipo de método privado, mas não. Tem perguntas sobre o `__` precedendo o nome do método aqui no SOpt, mas não estou achando.

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida se seria duplicata, então veja se essa minha resposta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189172/5878

Comment: Tem essa outra pergunta que trata do assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53028/5878

Comment: Além dos links já indicados, também tem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186982/112052 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/64985332 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447903/112052